# Contract does not exist

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, contract, fa1.2

I'm using a Granadanet node to experiment with Liquidity Baking. I'm trying to call the [tzBTC contract's `mint` entry point](https://tzkt.io/KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn/entrypoints).

This is my first time using a test net, but I thought that it was a copy of the previous main net + the new changes to be applied (Granada in this case). If this is correct, then I would expect the tzBTC contract here to exist on Granadanet.

However, when I attempt to call the [`mint` entry point of that contract](https://tzkt.io/KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn/entrypoints), I get the error `Contract KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn does not exist`.

Here is the command I am running to call that `mint` entry point:

```
tezos-client transfer 0 from alice to KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn \
                --entrypoint mint \
                --arg '(Pair "tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot" 100)' \
                --burn-cap 3
```

Here is the entire console out when I run the above command:

```
Waiting for the node to be bootstrapped...
Current head: BLoSXfco1Dj5 (timestamp: 2021-07-20T21:52:57.000-00:00, validation: 2021-07-20T21:53:07.132-00:00)
Node is bootstrapped.
This simulation failed:
  Manager signed operations:
    From: tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot
    Fee to the baker: ꜩ0
    Expected counter: 144380
    Gas limit: 1000
    Storage limit: 60000 bytes
    Revelation of manager public key:
      Contract: tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot
      Key: edpktobpzH61rWMtrx8AtAkJhDdW3DDuof71hwostS4uPqGottCXvE
      This revelation was successfully applied
      Consumed gas: 1000
  Manager signed operations:
    From: tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot
    Fee to the baker: ꜩ0
    Expected counter: 144381
    Gas limit: 1040000
    Storage limit: 60000 bytes
    Transaction:
      Amount: ꜩ0
      From: tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot
      To: KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn
      Entrypoint: mint
      Parameter: (Pair "tz1eYpX4e1nu7e3cvtF7UvKFqUvWDahte1ot" 100)
      This operation FAILED.

Contract KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn does not exist
Fatal error:
  transfer simulation failed
```

Comment: See P. Pinto's answer for the explanation. 
For a solution to this problem, you can use BCD interface to fork the contract from mainnet to testnet while preserving the storage: https://better-call.dev/mainnet/KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn/fork

Comment: If you want to try liquidity baking on granadanet, you need this contract: https://granadanet.tzkt.io/KT1VqarPDicMFn1ejmQqqshUkUXTCTXwmkCN (which is a testnet-version of tzBTC)

Comment: @Groxan I'm having a bear of a time trying to call that tzBTC contract, care to answer the question I just posted about it? https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/3607/cant-get-tzbtc-out-of-the-tzbtc-granadanet-contract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that it was a copy of the previous main net + the new changes to be applied (Granada in this case).

It isn't, testnets share no history with mainnet, or each-other. From the [Test Networks](http://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/test_networks.html) docs:

> every time a new protocol is proposed on Mainnet, a new test network is spawned. This also makes synchronization much faster than with a long-lived network.

So the contract you are trying to interact with indeed does not exist in `granadanet`.