# Can't get tzBTC out of the tzBTC Granadanet contract

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, michelson, contract, fa1.2

i'm trying to (eventually) add liquidity to the [Liquidity Baking CPMM contract on Granadanet](https://granadanet.tzkt.io/KT1TxqZ8QtKvLu3V3JH7Gx58n7Co8pgtpQU5/operations/). In order to add liquidity, I need some tzBTC [from the tzBTC contract here.](https://granadanet.tzkt.io/KT1VqarPDicMFn1ejmQqqshUkUXTCTXwmkCN/operations/). I cannot, for the life of me, call the tzBTC contract and get some tzBTC using the tezos-client.

It's not clear to me which [entrypoint](https://granadanet.tzkt.io/KT1VqarPDicMFn1ejmQqqshUkUXTCTXwmkCN/entrypoints) will give my wallet tzBTC, so I've tried calling `mintOrBurn`, `transfer` and `approve`.

Could someone please explain which entrypoint I need to call in order to get tzBTC, and explain how they know that/what they are looking at (so I can learn).

Also I'm using the `tezos-client` CLI and I'm having a bear of a time properly formatting my args when calling entrypoints, if someone could paste the `tezos-client` call I need to make I would be incredibly grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only admin can call `mintOrBurn` in that particular contract. As you can see [in the contract storage](https://granadanet.tzkt.io/KT1VqarPDicMFn1ejmQqqshUkUXTCTXwmkCN/storage/), `tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx` is the admin, so you need a private key from this address.

Fortunately, `tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx` is one of the bootstrap addresses with known private key `edsk3gUfUPyBSfrS9CCgmCiQsTCHGkviBDusMxDJstFtojtc1zcpsh`, which can be [imported to tezos-client](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/1839/53) and used to play with liquidity baking in granadanet.

I'm not a `tezos-client` guru, but I think the args should look like this:

```
tezos-client ... --entrypoint 'mintOrBurn' --arg 'Pair 100 "tz1blablabla..."'
```

Comment: hey this is very helpful, thank you. How do I use that known private key? I tried downloading a json wallet file from the faucet, and swapping the secret for the private key you gave and the ```pkh``` for tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx, but I get and error ```Invalid activation file: No case matched:
                             Missing object field activation_code
                             At /secret:
                               Unhandled error (Invalid_argument "Hex.to_char: 107 is an invalid char")```

Comment: You don't need to activate already existing bootstrap account. You need this: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/1839/53

Comment: Side question: where can one find these bootstrap peers secret keys?

Comment: This is great, thank you!

Comment: @Babell https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/bin_client/tezos-init-sandboxed-client.sh#L69-87